# Combine input type="text" and select tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of select elements:

```
<select id="id_tags_to" multiple="multiple" size="0" name="tags" class="filtered"></select>
```

I'd like to somehow either translate the entire list of select elements into text OR, populate a new form (with an input type=text) with the contents of the select elements list as one string of text.

I tried:

```
<form action="/search/{{search_type}})" method="get">
<input type="text" name="qTag">
<input type="submit" value=" Search Tags">
<select id="id_tags_to" multiple="multiple" size="0" name="tags" class="filtered"></select>
</form>
```

This did not work in that it not only did not accomplish what I'm trying to do but it also broke the select functionality.

In case its not very obvious, I have no experience with html or javascript or jquery, I'm just trying to get something working with temporary code, so any quick and dirty suggestion would be great.

Comment: Why you need to get the texts into new fields? You can access them via js

Comment: i'm working with code I didn't write, and not being familiar with js or html, I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you could use html5 to achieve that easily, its called a datalist its a new form type in html5 which is very useful hope this helps - Andrew

```
  <datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need that the `<select>` element contains some `<option>` elements. See [some reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)!

Then, you can get the list of select elements using javascript and populate it in the text field. Install jQuery and use [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/DdRRB/) to work on your code. I hope that helps you!